# Using jQuery select URL based off looped data

Tags: jquery

Using PHP I am looping through some data. The issue I have is trying to select a specific URL based on the site name using jQuery.

Here are the variables I have setup to collect the data from the PHP loop

```
 var attr = '{{ $review_site->site->name }}';
 var attrURL = '{{ $review_site->site_url }}';
 var attrID = '{{ $review_site->site_id }}';

 console.log("Sending to " + attr);
 console.log("URL is " + attrURL);
 console.log("Site ID is " + attrID);
```

Here is what my console log looks like

```
Google My Business
https://g.page/webpage
1
Facebook
https://www.facebook.com/pg/webpage/
2
```

The first line represents the site name, the second is the URL and the last is the Site ID. I am trying to identify the Google My Business site, grab the URL that is associated with it and do a window.location.replace

Here is the script I have written so far but it is not working

```
if (status) {
        if (attr == 'Google My Business') {
            window.location.replace("{{ $review_site->site_url }}");
        }
}
```

Here is what the looped data structure looks like:

```
                                    var site = [{
                                    "id": 8,
                                    "user_id": 2,
                                    "site_id": 1,
                                    "site_url": "https:\/\/google.com",
                                    "created_at": "2019-12-19 12:56:46",
                                    "updated_at": "2021-07-12 03:36:15",
                                    "site": {
                                        "id": 1,
                                        "name": "Google My Business",
                                        "logo": "google_business.jpg",
                                        "created_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35",
                                        "updated_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35"
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "id": 9,
                                    "user_id": 2,
                                    "site_id": 3,
                                    "site_url": "https:\/\/yelp.com",
                                    "created_at": "2020-02-12 10:05:29",
                                    "updated_at": "2021-07-12 03:36:30",
                                    "site": {
                                        "id": 3,
                                        "name": "Yelp",
                                        "logo": "yelp.png",
                                        "created_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35",
                                        "updated_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35"
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    "id": 19,
                                    "user_id": 2,
                                    "site_id": 2,
                                    "site_url": "https:\/\/facebook.com",
                                    "created_at": "2021-07-12 03:36:46",
                                    "updated_at": "2021-07-12 03:36:46",
                                    "site": {
                                        "id": 2,
                                        "name": "Facebook",
                                        "logo": "facebook_business.jpg",
                                        "created_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35",
                                        "updated_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35"
                                    }
                                }];
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `window.location.replace(attrURL );`

Comment: @Musa unfortunately that is not working, the issue is how do I tie the attr to the attrURL

Comment: What is the structure of the looped data?

Comment: @sideroxylon i added the looped data towards the bottom of the post

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
var mySites = [{
  "id": 8,
  "user_id": 2,
  "site_id": 1,
  "site_url": "https:\/\/google.com",
  "created_at": "2019-12-19 12:56:46",
  "updated_at": "2021-07-12 03:36:15",
  "site": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Google My Business",
    "logo": "google_business.jpg",
    "created_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35"
  }
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "user_id": 2,
  "site_id": 3,
  "site_url": "https:\/\/yelp.com",
  "created_at": "2020-02-12 10:05:29",
  "updated_at": "2021-07-12 03:36:30",
  "site": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Yelp",
    "logo": "yelp.png",
    "created_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35"
  }
}, {
  "id": 19,
  "user_id": 2,
  "site_id": 2,
  "site_url": "https:\/\/facebook.com",
  "created_at": "2021-07-12 03:36:46",
  "updated_at": "2021-07-12 03:36:46",
  "site": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Facebook",
    "logo": "facebook_business.jpg",
    "created_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-27 12:09:35"
  }
}];

$(function() {
  function populateSites(data, target) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      $("<option>", {
          value: item.site_url
        })
        .data("site-index", index)
        .html(item.site.name)
        .appendTo(target);
    });
  }

  function redirectTo(url) {
    if (url == "" || url == undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    window.location.redirect(url);
  }

  $("#site").change(function() {
    redirectTo($(this).val());
  });

  populateSites(mySites, $("#sites"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Site:
<select id="sites">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

You do not want to populate your Redirection with hard coded URL. This is what you are doing by populating it from your Server Side Script. Instead, you want to populate redirect when the User makes a selection.

You can do this in a few ways. The example I have presented populates the `value` attribute for each options with the URL. This makes it easy to collect. You could also use the Array Index as the `value` and then you know which the user selected and can pull the needed details from your Data.

E.G. If the User selected the second items from the drop down, "Yelp", you would get the array index of `1` and you can then pull up that data.

```
var results = confirm("You selected " + myData[1].site.name + ", which was most recently updated on " + myData[1].updated_at + ". Do you want  to proceed to this site?");
if(results){ redirectTo(myData[1].site_url) }
```

The `1` represents the array index and could also be a variable.